# Bootstrap | Two columns with one 16:9 video and some text

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, video, fullscreen

I would like to achieve something like that using Bootstrap:

```
|--------------------|------| ^
|                    | Some | |
|       16/9         | Text | | 90% height
|                    |      | |
|--------------------|------| v
<--------------------------->
   width 100% (screen width)
```

I've been able to create the two containers with the video keeping the 16/9 ratio, but the Div won't fit the remaining space. Instead, the video simply overtop the right DIV. Which mean the text I will add in my DIV will not be centered... As you can see there :

[image]

Can you please help me ?

Comment: You're using `col-md-4` for text col - it always takes 1/3 width of bootstrap row. If you don't want text and video to overlap you should _either_ recalc video height based on viewport width _or_ use, for example, flexbox instead of boostrap grid.

Comment: So I should use custom css to do it. Can you give me an hint about recalculing the video height ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to do it with Javascript. Kind of an Easy way to go.

```
<script>

var zvHeight = (screen.availHeight/100)*80;
var zvWidth = (zvHeight/9)*16;
document.getElementById('zv').style.width = zvWidth+"px";

zpsWidth = screen.availWidth-zvWidth;
document.getElementById('zps').style.width = zpsWidth+"px";
</script>
```